# Can my bot trade crypto for others?

Tags: software, cryptocurrency, securities

Is it legal if someone gives me their API key for phemex, with the intention that my bot ( which predicts and can trade each minute ) will trade for them?

Alternatively, if I license software which runs on their computer, is that more legal?

If the software runs on a computer in another country's jurisdiction, is that legal? ( I would be controlling it from the USA)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are seriously considering that as a business model, hire a specialist lawyer in your jurisdiction. You will need him or her.

- Usually, selling or licensing software would make the customer responsible for operating it lawfully. The programmer/vendor could still be held responsible if using it is illegal and there is a conspiracy, or if the software is considered export-restricted cryptography, or whatever.
- Running the software on your own servers might be considered providing financial services without the required permits.
- You could also be violating money-laundering laws if you handle your customers' cryptocurrency without proper permits and reporting. (If *your* program takes *their* API key, can a prosecutor claim that you are handling their money?)
- Hosting it abroad could make it less legal for the reasons above.
- Somebody (you or your customer) might be violating the TOS of the trading site.

As you can see, many "if" and "could" in there. **Either** forget it, **or** pay some real money to get expert advice. Also about liability if your software guesses wrong.

Comment: Sounds good. We're working on finding the right lawyer for the space.  Sounds like having a licensed piece that runs on their computer will be the most flexible, but for customer experience, it would be better if it was all hosted on our servers, so perhaps there is some brokerage process to go through.

Comment: @Funkodebat, I would be too scared to manage *the customers' keys* on my machine, and seriously concerned about a piece of software which does it on theirs. What if your software gets compromised? Can you get a waterproof liability disclaimer?

Comment: Waterproof to what depth?  Waterproofing is usually done down to a depth because pressure increases as you go deeper.  So, how about ocean floor waterproofing?  That's the goal!  This is what initial funding will be for.  It will have many waivers of liability, expressions of experimental-level risk, assurances that any money is considered gone at time of investment, and general south park levels of "and it's gone" risk tolerances.  That being agreed to, I think it'll still make people a bunch of money, heh.

Comment: @Funkodebat, I expect that consumer protection laws will limit what you can disclaim, but that's why you need a lawyer.